# особенности регулярных выражений excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Имеется исходная строка типа "Лист АМг6.М S ГОСТ 21631-76; HxL". Необходимо найти символы "SDHL" для последующей замены на фактические значения. Для такого поиска использую регулярное выражение "[\sx][DSLH][\sx]|$", которое правильно находит "S" и "Hx", но вместо "xL" выдает "". Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем моя ошибка? Думаю, что после нахождения "Hx" надо дать указание сдвинуть позицию начала поиска "xL" на один символ влево, но как? Спасибо

Comment: Никак. В регулярном выражении найденные фрагменты не могут пересекаться.

Comment: Задачка в данном виде выглядит как [XY problem](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY_(%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Каков ожидаемый результат на этих исходных данных? Во что должна превратиться строка?

Comment: После нахождения и замены исходная строка должна принять такой вид: "Лист АМг6.М 1,0 ГОСТ 21631-76; 50x100"

Comment: Здесь regex особо-то и не нужен, примените replace(). Для HxL конкретно замените "HxL" на "50x100".

Comment: Спасибо Станиславу и Алексею. Подозревал, но надежда оставалась. Таких материалов много, они находятся на отдельном листе и именно с символами в обозначении. Подмена на фактические значения происходит при создании чертежа в CATIA

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test1()
    tmp = "Лист АМг6.М S ГОСТ 21631-76; HxL"
    s = 1
    h = 50
    l = 100
    
    tmp = Replace(Replace(tmp, " S ", Format(s, "\ 0.0\ ")), "HxL", h & "x" & l)
    Debug.Print tmp
End Sub
```

```
Лист АМг6.М 1,0 ГОСТ 21631-76; 50x100
```

Answer (score 0):

Алексей, Вы правы, не полностью сформулированная задача приводит к ошибочным решениям. Я это обязательно учту, спасибо Вам. На самом деле на листе EXcel присутствует не только приведенное обозначение, но и "Труба Д16.Т.КР DxS ОСТ1 92096-83; L", "Пруток Д16ч.Т.КР D ОСТ1 90395-91; L" и т. п., т. е. вариантов взаимного сочетания символов "DSHL" достаточно много. Фактические значения находятся в таблице на поле чертежа CATIA. Задача сводится к нахождению символов в обозначении материалов и поиску их фактических значений в таблице чертежа. С учетом информации Станислава решение теперь выглядит так:

```
    Dim reg_str As String, reg_obj As Object, exec_obj As Object
    reg_str = "[\sx][DSLH]([\sx]|$)"
    title_mat = Replace(title_mat, "x", "x ")

    Set reg_obj = Utils.RegExpExecute(title_mat, reg_str)
    For Each exec_obj In reg_obj
        spec_letter = Trim(Replace(exec_obj, "x", ""))
        '... поиск фактического значения fact_size в таблице чертежа, CATIA VBA
        title_mat = Replace(Replace(title_mat, spec_letter, fact_size), "x ", "x")
    Next exec_obj
```